# Why doesn't it matter in which order define variables in class scope?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, initialization

If we execute such two lines in any function, we will get an error, and this is logical because the variable `b` is defined after the initialization `a = b`:

```cpp
int a = b;
int b = 0;
```

But when we insert these two lines into the scope of a class, why doesn't the class care about in which order `b` is defined?

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int a = b;
    int b = 0;
};
```

Comment: btw `struct` and `class` are just two keywords to define a class. The only difference is default access of members

Comment: note that most compilers will warn about this bug: https://godbolt.org/z/YfMGo9P8j

Comment: frankly its a little odd that you have accepted an answer (long ago) and now started the bounty to get a more detailed answer. Could you point out what you are missing from existing answers?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I would like to have a more detailed view of how the compiler does this initialization in class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does matter in which order you declare the members in a class.

The order determines in which order they are initialized. Using the default initializers like in your example is roughly equivalent to using this constructor with member initializer list:

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Foo() : a(b) , b(0) {}   // !! undefined !!
};
```

Here, still the order of initializion is determined by the order the members are declared, not by their order in the member initializer list. Compilers usually warn when the order is different. Though, in the above the problem gets more obvious: `a` is initialized with `b` before `b` is initialized. Reading from `b` before its initialization is undefined behavior.

To correctly iniitalize one member with the value of another you must respect the order:

```
class Foo
{
    int b = 0;  // initialized first
    int a = b;  // OK
};
```

Answer (score 13):

When you define the two non-member variables, they will be initialized immediately.

When you define the two member variables, the initialization will happen when the object is constructed, not when the variables are defined.

***However*** initialization is made in declaration order, so the initialization of `a` will use the uninitialized and *indeterminate* value of `b` which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: So this style of initialization always makes the wrong value for `a`?

Comment: @Jibel not always. If you swap their declaration they are initialized in right order and all is fine

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add a point:

In [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), section "Member function definition" says:

> For a name used inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification of a member function, or a **default member initializer**, the scopes searched are the same as in class definition, except that **the entire scope of the class is considered**, not just the part prior to the declaration that uses the name.

So you can even use `b` here before it is declared in classes.

---

Update: Just as the other answers say, `a` is initialized with `b`, but before `b` is initialized. See https://godbolt.org/z/MT86nd3Yr and you can find that `a` actually holds a trash value.